# Bokeh image affine transformation like matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, bokeh, python-3.7, affinetransform

I simply want to rotate an image by an aribitrary angle. In matplotlib, one can do this [affine transform](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/affine_image.html) at will. Is this possible with bokeh image plotting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Bokeh 2.1.1, only [`image_url`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html?highlight=image_url#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.image_url), which displays an image from a browser-reachable URL, directly supports an `angle` property to specify rotation. For `image` or `image_rgba` you could use something like [`PIL`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) to rotate the image before passing it to Bokeh.